# Porque é que uma hash em Bcrypt é diferente cada vez que é encriptada? Forma correta para comparação de passwords em Bcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bcrypt

Boas,

Estou a tentar criar um webpanel e um amigo sugeriu-me que fizesse a encriptação das passwords dos utilizadores com BCRYPT pela sua segurança.

O meu problema ao tentar iniciar sessão, a password encriptada que é guardada na database é diferente da que é enviada no request SQL.

Por exemplo, este é a parte principal do meu código para validar as credenciais do utilizador:

Ficheiro: passwordEncryptor.php

```
<?php
function passwordEncryptor($password){
$options = [
        'cost' => 14,
    ];
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
}

?>
```

Ficheiro: login.php

```
<?php
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['email']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pcd_users WHERE email='$email'";
    $do_query = @mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
    if($do_query){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($do_query) != 1){
            $errors[] = "E-mail ou Palavra-Passe incorretos.";
        }else{
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                if(pasword_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']){
                    mysqli_free_result($do_query);
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userNum'] = $row['num'];
                    header("Location: ./page.php");
                    exit();
                }else{
                    $errors[] = "E-mail ou Palavra-Passe incorretos.";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Erro: " . mysqli_error($do_query);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($do_query);
?>
```

Partindo do principio que a password guardada na database que foi enciptada usando a mesma função (passwordEncryptor) é `1234`, ou seja `$2y$14$gyyo5OaMe4SeXIhRStbdjOnZZrb3IOdCoIOQlzPZj15MhGBHUjniq`, porque é que no momento da autenticação a hash enviada é `$2y$14$O6iOBsAyv0JqwGudQhKPB.f68nLthfoMlJUU8n8zRuXxFJubhe7CO`

**Edit**

Após um pouco mais de pesquisa no site mãe, encontrei a [forma correta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/10935376) para verificar se a password introduzida é igual á encriptada que está na database.

> Por [Andrew Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26210/andrew-moore) na [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/10935376)
>
> ```
> if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
>     echo 'Password is valid!';
> } else {
>     echo 'Invalid password.';
> }
> ?>
> ```

Mas ainda assim fica a questão: Porque é que cada vez que é feita uma hash de uma string em bcrypt, a mesma é diferente?